# Get coordinates of a point in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel

I think i have a simple question, but i cannot find the answer anywhere!

I need to obtain the coordinates (X,Y) of some determinated pixels of a image in Photoshop CS6, how is the way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the INFO panel You can find the some details such as pixel coordinates, color parameters in the pixel where the cursor.

To get the INFO panel, go to Windows>Info or press F8 key.

If you want to change the unit, do as below image.

[image]

To find the size(Width & Height) of particular region, use Marque tool and select the region. It will show the size right section of the Coordinates in the INFO panel